# API Gateway, Where can I set method settings?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

It seems to me that AWS guys are adding new features all the time. I am watching Packt tutorial

[image]

Anyway, I can not find on my screen where I could set up authorization settings? 
This is how my screen looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on any method inside your resource, then you can found the `Method Request`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhdKg.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHXzQ.png